# Retrieve items by month and year with Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, date, select, doctrine

I need to retrieve all items of a particular type with Doctrine, where the 'date' field is stored as DateTime. Which means I'm working with the PHP DateTime object as well.

I need to do two things overall: if given a month and year, retrieve all records for that month and year; and if not given a month and year, retrieve all records for this month.

I've been looking at using BETWEEN statements in the Doctrine Query Builder, but can't figure out how to cleanly extract the month and year from PHP DateTime objects created 'now' so that the time portion of DateTime doesn't affect the query. I also can't see a way of just setting the day portion of the Date in DateTime to be 01 either, without affecting the month and year.

I thought this would be a fairly standard task but can't find a solution. Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

Found a hacky way to get the dates for between, but Doctrine is returning an empty array. Using the following code

```
/**
* Returns feed for month and year
*/
public function getMonthYearFeed($month, $year)
{
 // Create two times at the start of this month and next month
$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-n-Y',  "01-".$month."-".$year);
$startDate->setTime(0, 0 ,0);

$endDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-n-Y', "01-".($month+1)."-".$year);
$endDate->setTime(0, 0, 0);

$notes = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Note')->createQueryBuilder('n')->where('n BETWEEN :start AND :end')->setParameter('start', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->setParameter('end', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->getQuery()->getResult();

return $notes;
 }
```

Comment: Provide code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting something like this in your Repository should get you started. I haven't tested it aside from the `'last day of this month'` bit which seems to work fine.

```
/**
 * @param int $month
 * @param int $year
 * 
 * @return object[]
 */
public function findByDate($year = null, $month = null)
{
    if ($month === null) {
        $month = (int) date('m');
    }

    if ($year === null) {
        $year = (int) date('Y');
    }


    $startDate = new \DateTimeImmutable("$year-$month-01T00:00:00");
    $endDate = $startDate->modify('last day of this month')->setTime(23, 59, 59);

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('object');
    $qb->where('object.date BETWEEN :start AND :end');
    $qb->setParameter('start', $startDate->format('‌​Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $qb->setParameter('end', $endDate->format('‌​Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: DateTime modify changes the object and does not create a new instance so $startDate and $endDate would be the same. `$endDate = (clone $startDate)->modify('last day of this month')` should work though. Or just create a second instance.

Comment: Getting these errors when using the code An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT n0_.id AS id0, n0_.slug AS slug1, n0_.content AS content2, n0_.timestamp AS timestamp3, n0_.date AS date4, n0_.in_reply_to AS in_reply_to5 FROM note n0_ WHERE n0_.date BETWEEN ? AND ?' with params [{"date":"2016-08-01 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"}, {"date":"2016-08-31 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/London"}]:

Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTimeImmutable could not be converted to string

Comment: Try `$qb->setParameter('start', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));` and the same for the endDate

Comment: @Joe I used DateTimeImmutable which does not modify the date object. I guess that may also be the reason why an unmodified Doctrine refuses to accept the objects.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry i just stopped at DateTime since i rarely use immutable :) The reason why the conversion didn't work is in the next answer from the op. He forgot the `.date` part in the where condition. Nothing to do with the immutable DateTime.

Comment: The part of his error that say `class DateTimeImmutable could not be converted to string` kinda indicates that it does. I think the `.date`  comment refered to one of his earlier attempts that he didn't show us.

Comment: @Mrshll1001 I fixed the error in my answer that you were getting, try it again.

Comment: You are right i should read more carefully `WHERE n0_.date BETWEEN` in the error message indicates that information was unrelated. Anyways +1 for usage of `last date of this month` modifier. :)

Comment: Cheers! All fixed.

Comment: If you want to search for any date in the current month, I recommend to use 'first day of next month midnight' as ending date, it's simplier

Comment: See this fiddle http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b428088c5c9a119aa8fc1033a7a74361cd982217

Answer (score 0):

Very importand moment. Use data type of setParameter.

Like this for symfony.

> use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
>
> $query->setParameter('start', $startDate, Type::DATETIME);

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be working, although I will definitely need to modify the way I construct the dates (and move the function into the repo). I had originally forgotten the '.date' bit of DQL, and there was no need to output the DateTime object as a format.

```
// Create two times at the start of this month and next month
$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-n-Y', "01-".$month."-".$year);
$startDate->setTime(0, 0 ,0);

$endDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-n-Y', "01-".($month+1)."-".$year);
$endDate->setTime(0, 0, 0);

$notes = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Note')->createQueryBuilder('n')->where('n.date BETWEEN :start AND :end')->setParameter('start', $startDate)->setParameter('end', $endDate)->getQuery()->getResult();

// $notes = $this->em->getRepository('MrshllSiteBundle:Note')->findByDate();
return $notes;
```